# Error occured While writing to the file

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I am creating the File. At first time after creating the file, I'm immediately going to open a file but it shows error:

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProjectWork\Websites3\LogsArpita\ErrorLogs\Error_Log_24_4_2014.txt' because it is being used by another process."

What does it means? How can I open a file immediately for further write operation. I have tried with following code.

```
FileName = String.Concat("Error_Log_", DateTimeStamp + ext);

if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/LogsArpita/ErrorLogs/" + FileName)))
{
    File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/LogsArpita/ErrorLogs/" + FileName));
}

//Error occured here, below line
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/LogsArpita/ErrorLogs/" +    FileName), true);

tw.WriteLine("");
tw.Write("\"" + DateTimeStampLog + "\",");
tw.Write("\"Assignments.aspx\",");
tw.Write("\"" + ErrorMessage + "\",");
tw.Write("\"" + TransactVariable + "\"");
tw.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `File.Create` because the `StreamWriter` constructor will create the file if it does not exist

This is what the msdn documentation says:

> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

Comment: Moreover `File.Create` method creates and opens the file stream and returns the open stream. So when you use `File.Create` you should handle the returned stream, otherwise your each attempt to open that file will fail. But instead, you can just use the `StreamWriter` constructor and let it do its work.